# Load Random VOID method

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, void

I've create one content view for get news from `JSon`but i want load randomly.

I have 2 method:

```
- (void)radioNews {}
- (void)topNews {}
```

now i want get random radioNews or topNews in my `viewDidLoad`

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
           [self radioNews];
    }
```

this is correct only to load one method, is possible tell getRandom from `radioNews` and `topNews` and then in didLoad `[self methodResult]` ?

Thanks

Comment: I would suspect that `radioNews` and `topNews` are very similar and only differ in terms of some search parameter.  Therefore determine what differs and randomize on that data, not on the method to call.  You are most certainly duplicating alot of code.

Comment: is two different server of json and different array, so is more simple and fast do two method. you give me -1 for your assumption? the world of programmers is ruined by people like you, anyway thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSInteger random = arc4random()%2;
    if (random == 0) {
        [self radioNews];
    }else{
        [self topNews];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a `selector` from a `NSString`
Start creating a `NSArray` with `NSString`

```
// Define an NSArray of NSString, where a single string is the method name
NSArray *methods = @[@"radioNews", @"topNews"];
// Retrieve a random index
NSUInteger index = arc4random()%methods.count;
// You can use objectAtIndex without check the array bounds because
// the mod operation you did before will always return a value in bounds

// Create a selector instance from a string
SEL randomSelector = NSSelectorFromString([methods objectAtIndex: index]);
// Call the selector
[self performSelector:randomSelector 
           withObject:nil];
```